# SQL Join tables and show default value for unmatched records in the right table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables which I want them to be joined when certain condition has been met.

1) Clients Table

[image: Clients Table]

2) Payments Table

[image: Payments Table]

With these tables, I want to see how much each client has already paid.
***If a client has no payments made yet, the `amount` column should be `0`***

I had this SQL query but it won't show the clients without payments.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, co.amount FROM clients c LEFT OUTER JOIN collectibles co ON c.id = co.client_id WHERE co.removed = 0
```

The result of this query will only show 1 record and that is client `Cliff` with payment `25000`

How will I be able to achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use left join table's column in where.  this way  work as inner join  in these cases add the condition to the related  ON clause

```
  SELECT c.id
    , c.name
    , ifnull(co.amount ,0)
FROM clients c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN collectibles co ON c.id = co.client_id 
          AND co.removed = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join.  I think you want:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COALESCE(co.amount, 0) as amount
FROM clients c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     collectibles co
     ON c.id = co.client_id AND co.removed = 0;
```

You need `COALESCE()`to return `0` instead of `NULL`.